# Google chrome crashes with aw snap error on all sites

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome for long time on my windows machine.
Suddenly today it stopped working, and shows "Aw Snap" error on startup, and on any site.
The Settings page also crashes with the same error.
I've tried restart of the machine, uninstall and reinstall, but nothing works.

I've tried disabling extensions, and add log, but could not find any problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

The command I've used:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-logging --v=1 --disable-extensions
```

Windows Version:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1130]
```

and the log (only the end of it)

```
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:gaia_cookie_manager_service.cc(1017)] GaiaCookieManagerService::HandleNextRequest: no more
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:gaia_auth_util.cc(46)] Canonicalized @gmail.com to @gmail.com
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:gaia_auth_util.cc(46)] Canonicalized @gmail.com to @gmail.com
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(620)] AccountReconcilor::OnAccountsInCookieUpdated: CookieJar 0 accounts, Reconcilor's state is 1, Error was 
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(746)] AccountReconcilor::LoadValidAccountsFromTokenService: Chrome 0 accounts
[11652:9252:1218/210533.643:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(763)] AccountReconcilor::FinishReconcile
[11652:9252:1218/210533.644:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(900)] AccountReconcilor::CalculateIfReconcileIsDone: done
[11652:9252:1218/210533.644:VERBOSE1:account_consistency_mode_manager.cc(187)] Dice migration on next startup: 1
[11652:9252:1218/210533.644:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(911)] AccountReconcilor::StartReconcileIfChromeAccountsChanged
[11484:13476:1218/210535.226:VERBOSE1:proxy_resolution_service.cc(1340)] Failed configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
```

Comment: Did you try if another [browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) works?

Comment: yes, firefox is working fine

Comment: Chrome has a built in [malware scanner](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/chrome-has-a-built-in-malware-scanner-heres-how-to-use-it/). Try it and then perhaps make also a scan with a [malware remover](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/). If even this does not solve the problem, you can use Firefox in the meantime or try [Opera](https://www.opera.com), which is based on Chrome and is really very fast.

Comment: I get the "Aw Snap" error in the malware scanner page as well :(

Comment: In case anyone would encounter the same issue, the problem was symantec endpoint protection. I've removed it, and it works now.